# Understanding "unauthenticated email is not accepted due to domain's DMARC policy."

Tags: email, smtp

I did some digging and the closest thing I came to information regarding this issue was [this hostgator support document](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/email/dmarc-rejection-emails). I've tried that and the messages being sent by my server (coincidentally enough, run by hostgator) are still getting rejected even after using that advice.

How did you lot get around this?

Comment: The answer seems to be in the link itself? Don't use the `from @hostgator` in your from field, but rather use a domain name of your site?

Comment: As I explained in my intro, I tried that and no dice :(